# How do you sample an analogue image and store it in a true-colour frame buffer?

Tags: image-processing, noise, image, buffers, photometric

I really cannot get my head around on this issue - how does an analogue image is sampled and then stored in a ture-colour frame buffer (e.g. in a camera) and how do you prevent noise when you do so? Read multiple articles on it but I cannot really get it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you do and don't get? Right now we're just guessing about what kind of explanation would help you.

Comment: Well, it is an old computer graphics exam question, perhaps I should have started with this and I decided to work on it a bit to prepare myself for future examinations.

Comment: The question goes as stated "How does an analogue image is sampled and then stored in a ture-colour frame buffer (e.g. in a camera) and how do you prevent noise when you do so?"

Comment: The question is a bit ambiguous, are we talking about the A-to-D process that goes on in the sensor? Or are we talking about the bayer conversion camera sensor arrays need to apply to convert sensor data into RGB ?